# Prevent Visual Studio from Loading a Solution Project Without Using 'Solution Manager' Add-In

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Our Visual Studio 2010 solution contains an installer project that cannot be loaded unless the installation tool is installed. Since we only have one license for this tool, most developers receive an error message every time the solution is loaded. I know that you can mark a project as being unloaded, and this state is retained between invocations of VS, however, this option is only available when the project is loaded.

Is there a way to prevent VS from loading a project when the project cannot be loaded in the first place? I have tried the 'Solution Manager' add-in but it generates an error when launched in the context of our complex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the project from the solution, and create a new equivalent solution, which contains the project in question?

Or perhaps it is easier the other way around; create a new solution which contains all the projects except the one causing problems.

Comment: The installer project needs to be in the solution with the projects it is installing. Creating two solutions one with the installer project removed is just a big maintenance problem.